# Print Vector from Class

Tags: c++

I am trying to read a data file into a vector and print the values through class. When compiled there are no errors, but the program just stops after opening the file. Can't seem to figure out the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class circuit
{
    public:
        void openfile()
        {
            cout << "Enter input file name for time values: ";
            cin >> filename;
            infile.open(filename.c_str());
            while(infile.fail())
                {
                    cout << "Invalid file name." << endl;
                    cout << "Reenter file name: ";
                    cin >> filename;
                    infile.open(filename.c_str());
                }
        }

        void readfile()
        {
            while(infile >> t)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < time.size(); i++)
                {
                    time.push_back(t);
                }
            }
        }
        
        void print()
        {
            for(vector<double>::iterator i = time.begin(); i != time.end(); ++i) 
            {
                cout << *i << endl;
            }
        }

    private:
        string filename;
        ifstream infile;
        double t;
        vector<double> time;
        vector<double> Vout;
};

int main()
{
    circuit project;
    project.openfile();
    project.readfile();
    project.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged C?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: What about putting a `cout << t;` close to `time.push_back(t);`? also, what is the purpose of  this for loop enclosing the push_back? Maybe you should add the `cout` and comment out the `for`

Comment: What is the purpose of the for loop in `readline`? You never enter the loop because time is empty

Comment: Does your program actually stop in the middle or does it run to the end without outputting anything? There's a difference. Determining that will help you figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Please provide the exact inputs, the expected outputs, the actual outputs, a structured design chart, a sync and source analysis, an organizational mission statement, and a personal mission statement, or else we just can't tell what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've debugged it. Just take out

```
for (int i = 0; i < time.size(); i++)
{
}
```

but leave in the

```
time.push_back(t);
```

inside it, and it works fine.

I gave it a text file with four numbers in it separated by spaces, and it printed them out.

Since `time` never gets anything pushed back into it, it is always zero size; thus the loop always terminates without doing anything.

Here's the replacement method:

```
    void readfile()
    {
        while(infile >> t)
            time.push_back(t);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the openfile and readfile methods as follows:

```
void Circuit::openfile()
{
    cout << "Enter input file name for time values: ";
    cin >> filename;
    infile.open(filename.append(".txt")); // in my case I used a text file
    while (infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "Invalid file name." << endl;
        cout << "Reenter file name: ";
        cin >> filename;
        infile.open(filename.append(".txt"));
    }
}

void Circuit::readfile()
{
    string string_time;
    while (getline(infile, string_time)) {
         t = std::stod(string_time); //Converts string_time from string to double, assigns value to t
         time.push_back(t);
    }
}
```

My text file has one time value per line.